# how to save image path in the database in mysql for php

Tags: c#, php, vb.net

I have saved the data in database for the file upload but i am unable to store in the database mysql.
I have stored the uploaded image on desired location but  i want to know how to store the image path in the database. 
Html code:

```
</head>
<form action="file_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Name of Applicant:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" width="40px" name="nm"/>
</td>
</tr>
<br/>
<tr>
<td>
Email-Id:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" width="40px" name="email"/>
</td>
</tr>
<br/>
<tr>

<td>
mobile:
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" width="30px" name="mobile"/>
</td>
</tr>
<br/>
<tr>
<td>
Resume:</td>
<td>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</td>
</tr>


</table>
</form>
```

php code:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 50000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db1",$con);
mysql_query("insert into reg_job values('".$_POST["nm"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["mobile"]."')");
echo "Record inserted";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code:

```
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 50000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
 && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "doc" &&  $imageFileType != "xls" && $imageFileType != "pdf" && $imageFileType != "txt") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG,DOC,XLS,PDF,TXT & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
$file_path=$target_dir. basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
echo $file_path;
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db1",$con);
mysql_query("insert into reg_job values('".$_POST["nm"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["mobile"]."','".$file_path."')");
echo "Record inserted";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have database to store images then store the path of image like resource/aa.png then fire query in php like select image from imageTable.
get that data and replace it like 
                    $img=str_replace("/resources","",$images);
then u get aa.png after put it to your html page
" alt="">

Hope its work for you....